# "Calendar Storage" uninstalled. Calendar doesn't work

Tags: calendar, system-apps

I had uninstalled the **"Calendar Storage"** system app from my device. Now I cannot use my Calendar Application. I assume this because I had uninstalled Calendar Storage.

I haven't got any backup for restoring that app. I have even tried factory reset, but I cannot get the app back. Now I need to get an apk file of the app, move it to /system/app/ and reinstall. But I cannot find the correct apk file of the app for my device.

**I am using iBall Slide i9018 (rooted) running on android 4.2.**
Please help me find the correct apk file of the app for my device.

Comment: Hi! Questions asking us app suggestion/recommendation are off-topic here. See [help/on-topic] to know more. But your question has  on-topic issue, so I recommend an edit to purge the part asking us to find the app. Instead, simply ask what to do now.

Comment: Simple answer is: 1) factory reset wouldn't help because you removed a system app, that is, an app which is part of factory state of OS, so reset won't help. 2) You may end up at a malicious apk if you go on a hunt like this. Simply download the correct firmware, extract the APK, and load it into the system. You may see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152)